# Filter div based in its id

Tags: jquery, filter

I can succesfully hide the divs that contains a string in the id with this code:

The button:

```
<input type="button" id="mytest" value="filter"></input>
```

The js code:

```
//hides divs with class=screen3 and with 99 in its id
$('#myteste').click (function () {
    $('div.screen3[id*="99"]').hide();
});
```

Now I need to do the opposite, to hide divs that doesn't contain the string in it's id but I don't know how.

Comment: Hi Math! I'm trying to do something similar to this (hiding div's based on their id when searching), would you mind sharing your code?

Comment: @John I believe this is the code you're loonking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568750/filter-div-based-in-its-id?noredirect=1#comment20329621_14568778 Does it help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that :

```
$('div.screen3').not('[id~="99"]').hide(); // tests the word (delimited by spaces)
```

or

```
$('div.screen3').not('[id*="99"]').hide(); // tests the string
```

Comment: `$('div.screen3').not('[id*="99"]').hide();` worked perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try using :not

```
$('#myteste').click (function () {
    $('div.screen3:not([id*="99"])').hide();
});
```

Comment: +1 this is more general than `!=` and I believe it's more readable as well.